# Android RecyclerView solution of notifyItemRemoved(position) without animation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have situation where in long list I remove item at specific position. Now I update it in my variable that holds the list, but I also need to notify adapter.
I would like to avoid using notifyDataSetChanged() since in my opinion it wastes resources in this case.

So I use:

```
 notifyItemRemoved(homeItems.size - 1)
```

But what happens here is that when I shoot this function, it scrolls my list to the beginning. Since I am using pagination in my app, this looks very bad. I want to stay on the same position I scrolled to. Is it possible to avoid this animation?
If not is there any other way to solve this situation by notifying adapter that only 1 element changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable animations by adding following line to recycler view

```
recyclerView.itemAnimator = null
```

This will disable all the default animations

**For java**

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Comment: Nope this does not solve issue. The behaviour stays the same